# Alpinejs x-show syntax issue

Tags: alpine.js

I am filtering a grid of logos based on a category that is contained in an array of data. I am having trouble getting the syntax correct for pulling the category into the x-show directive.
Here is what I have that is not working-

x-show="tab === '`${item.cat}`' || tab === 'all'"

Can someone please show me what the correct syntax would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a directive you use regular JS, therefore:

```
x-show="tab === item.cat || tab === 'all'"
```

Or use backticks (`) for template literals.